# Missing Client Secret or Client Certificate

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

MsalClientException: IDW10104: Both client secret and client certificate cannot be null or whitespace, and only ONE must be included in the configuration of the web app when calling a web API. For instance, in the appsettings.json file.

```
Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityOptionsValidation.ValidateEitherClientCertificateOrClientSecret(string clientSecret, IEnumerable<CertificateDescription> cert)
Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.BuildConfidentialClientApplicationAsync()
Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetOrBuildConfidentialClientApplicationAsync()
Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.AddAccountToCacheFromAuthorizationCodeAsync(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context, IEnumerable<string> scopes)
Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthenticationBuilder+<>c__DisplayClass11_1+<<WebAppCallsWebApiImplementation>b__1>d.MoveNext()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RunAuthorizationCodeReceivedEventAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage authorizationResponse, ClaimsPrincipal user, AuthenticationProperties properties, JwtSecurityToken jwt)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
```

This occurs after a successful sign-in via Azure AD.  I have passed in the client secret as well  (via user-secrets and appSettings). For source code reference, I am using the following example project:

https://github.com/damienbod/AspNetCoreUsingGraphApi

Comment: Please share your appSettings where you configure the client secret and the code how it is used.

Comment: Is that you want to call microsoft graph in web application?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to call web api projected by AzureAD in web app, please refer to the following steps

1. `appsettings.json`

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "ClientId": "[Client_id-of-web-app-eg-2ec40e65-ba09-4853-bcde-bcb60029e596]",
    "TenantId": "common"

   // To call an API
   "ClientSecret": "[Copy the client secret added to the app from the Azure portal]",

 },
 "MyApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
    }
}
```

2. `startup.cs`

```
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

public class Startup
{
  // ...
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
  {
  // ...
  services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration, "AzureAd")
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[]{"" })
               .AddDownstreamWebApi("MyApi", Configuration.GetSection("MyApi"))
            .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
   // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

3. call api

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
 readonly ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition;

 public HomeController(ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
 {
  this.tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
 }

 [AuthorizeForScopes(Scopes = new[] { "user.read" })]
public async Task<IActionResult> Profile()
{
 // Acquire the access token.
 string[] scopes = new string[]{"user.read"};
 string accessToken = await tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);

 // Use the access token to call a protected web API.
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
 string json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
}

}
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-app-call-api-overview).